# Trace32 command get struct members/elements name

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I found that `WinPrint` or `Var.WRITE` can only write up to **4095** bytes to the file at a time. For larger size structures, the data out of limits will be lost. To avoid this, we can write multiple times according to the member order.

( If we only know the name of a structure and load the elf through T32, we can find it in the symbol list and view all its members. So, **can we get the member name of the structure by some T32 command** and then log to file according to the name like `Var.WRITE #1 StructA.memberName` )

Comment: Of course, we can use elf/dwarf to get the names of struct member, and then use them as the input of  T32 cmm/practice script, But does Trace32 itself provide a more convenient way?

Answer (score 0):

```
WinPrint.<command>
```

The `WinPrint` pre-command is used to generate a hardcopy or a file from **one command**. The numbers of
columns and lines in the window are adapted to the possibilities of the printer. Printer selection can be
executed by the `PRinTer` command.

Thus, the output can also be re-routed to a file. In the case of some commands, extended parameters are
possible for printing more than one page.

```
WinPrint.var.view %m.3 %r.3 structName
```

This command can output all the contents of the structure to a file. Because `var.view` is not restricted by 4095, all the contents can be saved to a file.

**m** stands for multiline. It displays the structure elements in multiple line format. If the elements are in a multidimensional array, the numeric parameter defines the number of levels displayed.

**r** stands for recursive. This optional number defines the depth of recursion to be displayed. The command SETUP.VarPtr defines the valid address range for pointers. The contents of pointers outside this range are not displayed.